# Painted Pony beans pate

Tags: spices, flavor, garlic, beans, basil

I'm going to make a pate using `Painted Pony` beans as a base. I want to add roasted walnuts, but I don't know whether basil and garlic would be acceptable to put to the dish.

- Would this make for a bad flavor combination?
- What further spices would you recommend incorporating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well basil and garlic could fit well with the walnuts (think about pesto, basil, garlic, cheese and nuts).

With the bean paste... I don't know, I guess it depends what kind of tone you would like to give to the dish.
Stated that the only way to know is to try, I would also try with nutmeg and, if you're brave, maybe even a pinch of cinnamon!

Comment: Thanks! I can't even imagine how could cinnamon taste with other ingredients)

Comment: @helicera: well, let us know if it works then! (I wouldn't go too strong with the cinnamon, anyway)

Comment: Garlic is definitely fine with beans. I haven't encountered the combination with basil, but wouldn't worry about it, it doesn't sound like it would clash.

Comment: @rumtscho: Beans with basil are also very good, as they are with garlic and parsley.